# How can I make an associative array from every two offsets of a normal array?

Tags: php, arrays, csv, associative-array

I have an array of paired values (name, and email) and I'm trying to make an associative array from a normal array for every two offsets. Example:

```
Array
 (
    [0] => joe
    [1] => joe@gmail.com
    [2] => bill
    [3] => bill@gmail.com
    [4] => kyle
    [5] => kyle@gmail.com
    [6] => matt
    [7] => matt@gmail.com
    [8] => chris
    [9] => chris@gmail.com
)
```

I would like to make an associative array for each `[$i]` & `[$i+1]`, so it would look like:

```
Array
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => joe
            [email] => joe@gmail.com
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => bill
            [email] => bill@gmail.com
        )
 )
```

I tried :

```
$num = count($csvArray);
for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i+2) {
    $newArray[] = array(
        'name' => $csvArray[$i],
        'email' => $csvArray[$i+1]
    );
}
```

It gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\array.php on line 20

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What line is line 20 of the `array.php` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a problem in your for loop... it should be

```
for($i=0; $i < $num; $i=$i+2)
```

currently it's not getting incremented and hence the infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

```
$newArray = array_chunk($csvArray, 2);
```

Comment: Perfect solution if you ask me.